# Auto refreshing google blog content automatically every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogspot

When I update the content using google blogger API, the contentString goes inside an li tag.

```
<li class="item" data-id="7225215730495036885">
ContentString
</li>
```

I need to auto refresh this li tag automatically every 30 seconds.

Note : I don't want to refresh the entire webpage; Just the li tag. It's also sufficient for me to refresh a `<table>` tag which is part of my content string.

Comment: Need some more information.  How are you getting the item content originally?  On page load?    Can you provide some details to the google blogger api on how one could retrieve the updated string?

Comment: I use a java program which updates the blog every 30 seconds.

On page load, we can see the most recently updated content.

Comment: Is the item being updated a post?  Does the ID change when you modify the blog?  The api does allow for retreiving specific posts https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingASpecificPost

Comment: No. The data-id is constant for a blog. Only the content gets updated.

Comment: are you able to call a e.g. PHP-script via AJAX? If so you could create a javascript timer which makes a AJAX-call every x seconds and then passes the result into your div with known id

Comment: A code snippet please (newbie here)..